# Freebase: constrain property to be empty

Tags: freebase, mql

Is there a way to constrain a property to be empty in a Freebase query? In particular, I want to find all the properties that have unique=null and /freebase/type_hints/mediator=null. So something like this:

```
[{
  type: "/type/property",
  unique: null,
  "expected_type" : {
    "/freebase/type_hints/mediator" : null
  }
}]​
```

except I want the null to actually mean a null value for those properties. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `"optional": "forbidden"`.

```
[{
  "id":     null,
  "name":   null,
  "type":   "/type/property",
  "unique": {
    "value":    null,
    "optional": "forbidden"
  },
  "expected_type": {
    "/freebase/type_hints/mediator": {
      "value":    null,
      "optional": "forbidden"
    }
  }
}]​
```

In general, you don't need anything other than the `"optional": "forbidden"` in the clause, but MQL doesn't let you have a clause containing only directives and no actual properties so the `"value": null` is just there to keep it happy.

Comment: You'll need to replicate the "optional":"forbidden" clause to the "unique" property if you wanted that one to be empty as well.  I think the semantics of the "unique" property are that null == False, if that matters to what you're trying to do.

Comment: @TomMorris: good point about `unique`; I've edited my answer. The point about the semantic equivalence between empty and false is perhaps even more important - while the vast majority (21181) of non-mediator types have `/freebase/type_hints/mediator` empty, a non-trivial number (326) have it explicitly set to false, and this includes a number of rather important types (eg `/location/country` and `/people/person`); I haven't checked for `unique`, but I suspect the same problem applies. Fixing that is less trivial.